# libgdx SpriteBatch UnsatisfiedLinkError desktop

Tags: gradle, libgdx, desktop-application, unsatisfiedlinkerror, spritebatch

I am getting UnsatisfiedLinkError in a LibGdx project, when trying to run a desktop standalone version of it. Note, this problem doesn't occur if I simply run a desktop version directly without building a standalone jar for it, only if I build a desktop jar first, and then try to run that. It is interesting to note that, it was overall a lot easier to run the desktop version directly, and I wasn't even to come close to running a standalone desktop jar until I hunted down a whole bunch of jar files, and added them manually to the LibGdx project.

I am using Android Studio 3.3, with gradle 4.10, and Java 1.8.0_201 on Windows 10 x64, and have deployed a version of my LibGdx app to the desktop, using the 'gradle' command:

`gradle desktop:dist` from the ProjectRoot.

And then upon running the jar file created by that, by typing into the command line from the ProjectRoot:

`cd desktop/build/libs`, then `java -jar desktop-1.0.jar`

upon doing so I get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError error`

I tried copying the jar file over to Linux and tested it there too, and I got the same error.

I did some searching, and I found [a suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436344/unsatisfiedlinkerror-libgdx-desktop) that it might be that the call to `new SpriteBatch()` was happening too early:

as in before the `create()` function in the core module, but that wasn't the problem, because the `new SpriteBatch()` call was never any earlier than that.

Also the suggestion from that link to use the `LibGdx Setup Generator` didn't help me, because I already used that `LibGdx Setup Generator` GUI tool to create this same project, and I'm still having this problem.

I noticed though that from the output of the program, that it was throwing that UnsatifisedLinkError exception on the `new SpriteBatch()` call, as that link did make a reference to, but it was being called from the `create()` function, and not earlier than that.

I did an experiment and found that if I removed the `new SpriteBatch()` call altogether and all other code that depended on that call, such as creating a texture, and using the sprite batch to draw that texture. I found that by doing that, the program ran without getting the error, of course I also wasn't able to draw anything that way.

So, then I did another experiment and moved the `new SpriteBatch()` call out of the create function and down into the `render()` function in the following way, as you will notice in the code. I simply tried to create the SpriteBatch() every time the render() function executes, if it hasn't already been created, and output how many times it threw the `UnsatisfiedLinkError exception`

-------------------------MyGdxGame.java--------------------------------------

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;
    long numAttempts = 0;

    @Override
    public void create () {

    }

    @Override
    public void render () {

        if (batch == null) {
            try {
                batch = new SpriteBatch();
            } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError error) {
                System.out.println("Failed create SpriteBatch attempt #" + numAttempts);
                ++numAttempts;
            }

            if (batch != null) {
                img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
            }
        }

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        //batch.begin();
        //batch.draw(img, img.getWidth(), 0);
        //batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        //batch.dispose();
        //img.dispose();
    }
}
```

---

That code above ended up creating this output:

```
Failed create SpriteBatch attempt #0
Failed create SpriteBatch attempt #1
Failed create SpriteBatch attempt #2
Failed create SpriteBatch attempt #3
Failed create SpriteBatch attempt #4
Failed create SpriteBatch attempt #5
Failed create SpriteBatch attempt #6
Failed create SpriteBatch attempt #7
Failed create SpriteBatch attempt #8
Failed create SpriteBatch attempt #9
Failed create SpriteBatch attempt #10
Failed create SpriteBatch attempt #11
Failed create SpriteBatch attempt #12
```

---

And it seems it would have just kept on going, saying "Failed create SpriteBatch attempt #..." if I had allowed the app to keep running.

As, you can see, it seems like no matter how many render frames have occurred, `new SpriteBatch()` throws the `UnsatifiedLinkError` exception, so this is clearly not a  problem simply because I called `new SpriteBatch()` too early in the program.

I also saw another suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495708/libgdx-box2d-unsatisfiedlinkerror) that I should I do something like this for the desktop version:

```
static {
    GdxNativesLoader.load();
}
```

And somewhere else, I don't remember where, I saw this suggestion:

```
LwjglNativesLoader.load();
```

so I tried both of these, not at the same time though, and neither worked, I did so by putting them in the DesktopLauncher file as so:

--------DesktopLauncher.java-------------------------------------------

```
package com.mygdx.game.desktop;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglNativesLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader;
import com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame;

public class DesktopLauncher {

    static {
        //GdxNativesLoader.load(); // I tried with this line of code
        //LwjglNativesLoader.load(); // and separately with this line
    }

    public static void main (String[] arg) {

        //GdxNativesLoader.load(); // and separately with this line, here

        //LwjglNativesLoader.load(); // and separately with this line, here


        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();

        new LwjglApplication(new MyGdxGame(), config);
    }
}
```

---

None of that fixed it. I also remember seeing some links that were suggesting maybe there is a mismatch in my gdx native jars and my gdx jar, but I wasn't sure how to check that, but I will show my list of jars that I added to `desktop/libs` folder and my `gradle.build` file:

--------jar files:-------------

```
core-1.0.jar
desktop-1.0.jar
gdx-1.9.9.jar
gdx-backend-lwjgl-1.9.9.jar
gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar
gdx-natives.jar
gdx-openal.jar
gdx-platform-1.9.9.jar
jinput-2.0.5.jar
jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-linux.jar
jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-osx.jar
jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar
jutils-1.0.0.jar
lwjgl-2.9.0.jar
lwjgl-2.9.2.jar
lwjgl-3.2.1.jar
lwjgl-openal-3.2.1.jar
lwjgl-platform-2.9.2-natives-linux.jar
lwjgl-platform-2.9.2-natives-osx.jar
lwjgl-platform-2.9.2-natives-windows.jar
```

---

And here is the part of my build.gradle file where I include the jar files I needed to add manually to even get a desktop standalone version of my LibGdx version to run at all:

----part of my build.gradle file-----------

```
project(":desktop") {

    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")

        // ... a bunch of irrelevant implementation lines here

        compile files("libs/gdx-1.9.9.jar")
        compile files("libs/gdx-backend-lwjgl-1.9.9.jar")
        compile files("libs/lwjgl-2.9.0.jar")
        compile files("libs/core-1.0.jar")
        compile files("libs/desktop-1.0.jar")
        compile files("libs/gdx-natives.jar")

        // Noticed I commented these ones out
        // compile files("libs/gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar")
        //compile files("libs/gdx-platform-1.9.9.jar")
        //compile files("libs/lwjgl-3.2.1.jar")

        compile files("libs/lwjgl-openal-3.2.1.jar")
        compile files("libs/jinput-2.0.5.jar")

        // Noticed I also commented out these
        //compile files("libs/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-linux.jar")
        //compile files("libs/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-osx.jar")
        //compile files("libs/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar")
        //compile files("libs/jinput-1.0.0.jar")

        compile files("libs/jutils-1.0.0.jar")
        compile 'org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl:2.9.2'
        compile files("libs/lwjgl-2.9.2.jar")
        compile files("libs/lwjgl-platform-2.9.2-natives-linux.jar")
        compile files("libs/lwjgl-platform-2.9.2-natives-osx.jar")
        compile files("libs/lwjgl-platform-2.9.2-natives-windows.jar")
    }
}
```

---

In case you're wondering, I always make sure my `core-1.0.jar` and `desktop-1.0.jar` are up to date, by building my desktop version, copying those jars into `desktop/libs` folder, and then rebuilding that, so that's not part of the problem.

Anyway, so after all this research, and all these experiments, I have yet failed to find the cause of and solution to my problem. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you very much!

Post edit:

My classpath is this:

```
0: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\charsets.jar
1: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\deploy.jar
2: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar
3: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar
4: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar
5: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar
6: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar
7: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar
8: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar
9: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar
10: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar
11: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar
12: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar
13: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar
14: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\javaws.jar
15: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jce.jar
16: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jfr.jar
17: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar
18: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jsse.jar
19: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\management-agent.jar
20: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\plugin.jar
21: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\resources.jar
22: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\rt.jar
23: C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\TestHtml\desktop\build\classes\java\main
24: C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\TestHtml\desktop\build\classes\kotlin\main
25: C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\TestHtml\core\build\classes\java\main
26: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\de.tomgrill.gdxdialogs\gdx-dialogs-core\1.2.5\c55ef7e82d013ea7d99a66dcbdc24cfa7127337e\gdx-dialogs-core-1.2.5.jar
27: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.box2dlights\box2dlights\1.4\3d77ad5b4164fb32fc67e2446e35911bb0aaf0bd\box2dlights-1.4.jar
28: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils\libgdx-utils-box2d\0.13.4\918d79a20ea3c898cdb3611782c5b2bfa6ec575b\libgdx-utils-box2d-0.13.4.jar
29: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-box2d\1.9.9\e9a43c50fbe4f1e26dd0af5d2e78d125549e7f6b\gdx-box2d-1.9.9.jar
30: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.ashley\ashley\1.7.0\a7c4083c0a42027a3c03ba7ccecef6cbe1c5f0a4\ashley-1.7.0.jar
31: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-ai\1.8.0\ec30677d8ab1a8b8aa4b853c5f4e4b1361f50bf5\gdx-ai-1.8.0.jar
32: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-controllers\1.9.9\55b69a040e076b17d01a5057f9cb2ce338a3331a\gdx-controllers-1.9.9.jar
33: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.czyzby\gdx-lml-vis\1.9.1.9.6\951c197ebe8c9644bd555722c449fa4cfda527fb\gdx-lml-vis-1.9.1.9.6.jar
34: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.kotcrab.vis\vis-ui\1.3.0\639741faa66a560197ee06a9412949402c831796\vis-ui-1.3.0.jar
35: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils\libgdx-utils\0.13.4\27affad2873d1c9c366a2290fc51f3927f3a5f83\libgdx-utils-0.13.4.jar
36: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook\gdx-facebook-core\1.4.1\1b5d4948b033a4b9a8f360d0fa76c49e6e17baec\gdx-facebook-core-1.4.1.jar
37: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx\1.9.9\bf26f2f816b3cfe37ac6e66615391c30714b7030\gdx-1.9.9.jar
38: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.esotericsoftware.spine\spine-libgdx\3.6.53.1\281f862762c15a8f8a79443a57526f4238b52b8e\spine-libgdx-3.6.53.1.jar
39: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.czyzby\gdx-lml\1.9.1.9.6\2590018dd6fc37566e3998db2cc2ecce0155c3b4\gdx-lml-1.9.1.9.6.jar
40: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.czyzby\gdx-kiwi\1.9.1.9.6\c00391b240ccf1212f3acd2095b6df489d4ff281\gdx-kiwi-1.9.1.9.6.jar
41: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-tools\1.9.9\55228989f0479dd4bbe487766eda15e5d512c51e\gdx-tools-1.9.9.jar
42: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-backend-lwjgl\1.9.9\ca8911cb94c0bfeb59f99e46ca9b92440958fb0e\gdx-backend-lwjgl-1.9.9.jar
43: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.2\4b9e37300a87799856e0bd15ed81663cdb6b0947\lwjgl_util-2.9.2.jar
44: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.2\a9d80fe5935c7a9149f6584d9777cfd471f65489\lwjgl-2.9.2.jar
45: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-platform\1.9.9\7e644cfafdb436b13b24ac7993ffab17f306b64d\gdx-platform-1.9.9-natives-desktop.jar
46: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-box2d-platform\1.9.9\72b2916f45f3f948896eda931cd597f7e698340f\gdx-box2d-platform-1.9.9-natives-desktop.jar
47: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-controllers-desktop\1.9.9\d4b8b62f077382db145e7a94a27a994b68ce6ee\gdx-controllers-desktop-1.9.9.jar
48: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-controllers-platform\1.9.9\26b8735060fdfd7dc6529cf5085fa57144a349d9\gdx-controllers-platform-1.9.9-natives-desktop.jar
49: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook\gdx-facebook-desktop\1.4.1\709e9a585082d7b875540d33ee3a4f4787ea74c3\gdx-facebook-desktop-1.4.1.jar
50: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\de.tomgrill.gdxdialogs\gdx-dialogs-desktop\1.2.5\233048054a845d7a59d86c54e9d74f95749f74b5\gdx-dialogs-desktop-1.2.5.jar
51: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8\1.3.20\b1f3cb184c4ce4139741454df2f8fca5320f822d\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.20.jar
52: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.2\510c7d317f5e9e700b9cfaac5fd38bdebf0702e0\lwjgl-platform-2.9.2-natives-windows.jar
53: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.2\d276cdf61fe2b516c7b7f4aa1b8dea91dbdc8d56\lwjgl-platform-2.9.2-natives-linux.jar
54: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.2\d55b46b40b40249d627a83a7f7f22649709d70c3\lwjgl-platform-2.9.2-natives-osx.jar
55: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jinput\jinput\2.0.5\39c7796b469a600f72380316f6b1f11db6c2c7c4\jinput-2.0.5.jar
56: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-backend-headless\1.9.9\657d1d232f274162eb8fd600a137b2221f2fc9c\gdx-backend-headless-1.9.9.jar
57: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-freetype\1.9.9\d947872087863b654d9a0e27a8cb10a29d6fd3d6\gdx-freetype-1.9.9.jar
58: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.jlayer\jlayer\1.0.1-gdx\7cca83cec5c1b2f011362f4d85aabd71a73b049d\jlayer-1.0.1-gdx.jar
59: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jcraft\jorbis\0.0.17\8872d22b293e8f5d7d56ff92be966e6dc28ebdc6\jorbis-0.0.17.jar
60: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7\1.3.20\aa17d6fd473ce53061a7b2b9d2ae96f547cae93d\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.20.jar
61: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.3.20\eb2a232734e09fcd1b958a5c7520a93c6de38b32\kotlin-stdlib-1.3.20.jar
62: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jutils\jutils\1.0.0\e12fe1fda814bd348c1579329c86943d2cd3c6a6\jutils-1.0.0.jar
63: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\7ff832a6eb9ab6a767f1ade2b548092d0fa64795\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-linux.jar
64: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\385ee093e01f587f30ee1c8a2ee7d408fd732e16\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar
65: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\53f9c919f34d2ca9de8c51fc4e1e8282029a9232\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-osx.jar
66: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.3.20\7d7934e26ce34da1a0a8d00e38038d7cf3375e89\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.20.jar
67: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar
68: C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\TestHtml\desktop\libs\core-1.0.jar
69: C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\TestHtml\desktop\libs\gdx-natives.jar
70: C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\TestHtml\desktop\libs\lwjgl-3.2.1.jar
71: C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\TestHtml\desktop\libs\lwjgl-natives-linux.jar
72: C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\TestHtml\desktop\libs\lwjgl-natives-macos.jar
73: C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\TestHtml\desktop\libs\lwjgl-natives-windows.jar
74: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\idea_rt.jar
```

Update:

My full desktop module in build.gradle:

```
   project(":desktop") {
    //apply plugin: "application"
    //mainClassName = "DesktopLauncher"
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-desktop:$gdxVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        implementation "de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook:gdx-facebook-desktop:1.4.1"
        implementation "de.tomgrill.gdxdialogs:gdx-dialogs-desktop:1.2.5"

        //implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:1.9.9"
        compile files("libs/gdx-1.9.9.jar")
        compile files("libs/gdx-backend-lwjgl-1.9.9.jar")
        //compile files("libs/lwjgl-2.9.0.jar")
        compile files("libs/core-1.0.jar")
        //compile files("libs/desktop-1.0.jar")
        compile files("libs/gdx-natives.jar")
        // compile files("libs/gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar")
        //compile files("libs/gdx-platform-1.9.9.jar")
        //compile files("libs/lwjgl-3.2.1.jar")

        /*
        compile files("libs/lwjgl-openal-3.2.1.jar")
        compile files("libs/jinput-2.0.5.jar")
        compile files("libs/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-linux.jar")
        compile files("libs/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-osx.jar")
        compile files("libs/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar")
        */

        //compile files("libs/jinput-1.0.0.jar")

        compile files("libs/jutils-1.0.0.jar")


        compile 'org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl:2.9.2'
        compile files("libs/lwjgl-3.2.1.jar")

        compile files("libs/lwjgl-platform-2.9.2-natives-linux.jar")
        compile files("libs/lwjgl-platform-2.9.2-natives-osx.jar")
        compile files("libs/lwjgl-platform-2.9.2-natives-windows.jar")

        compile files("libs/lwjgl-natives-linux.jar")
        compile files("libs/lwjgl-natives-macos.jar")
        compile files("libs/lwjgl-natives-windows.jar")
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem has something to do with the native jars or the lwjgl jars, remember, there is still a bounty on this question of 50 points to whoever can find the solution for me.

Comment: no help yet after 5 days on bounty - well, I've come to realize now that the error is actually a runtime linker error, but I haven't yet figured out how to solve it, I tried replacing "compile" with natives for the native jars in gradle and that just gave me this error: 

Could not find method natives() for arguments [file collection] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

still looking for help

Comment: Wow no answer even after a bounty expired

Comment: My answer previously wasn't a solution to your problem. It wasn't incorrect, but i didn't take into account the fact that libgdx was supposed to pack natives already.

Comment: The fact though that adding `GdxNativesLoader.load();` in a static block isn't working, makes me believe the problem is definitely with your classpath. Not with any code.

Comment: Maybe try re-creating the project with the following tool: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle

Comment: Thank you, but that tool is the tool I already used to create the project.

Comment: @Dylan, I updated my question to show the paths that happen to be in my Java classpath, which I obtained by checking System.getProperty("java.class.path")

Comment: @Dylan, there is now a new bounty of 100 points on the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change build.gradle contents as below, sync gradle again and check it once.

```
project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:1.9.9"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.9:natives-desktop"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:1.9.9:natives-desktop"

    }
}
```

I think you are using extra unnecessary libraries which are not require.

I have added one working sample project over bitbucket you can clone it from and compare with yours

```
git clone https://zumbarlalsaindane@bitbucket.org/zumbarlalsaindane/libgdx-test.git
```

Before running the application do below step:

```
   Go to Run => Run Configurations.. => choose DesktopLauncher, Arguments Tab
   => Working Directory => Others then browse to yourproject-android/assets/ 
   and click Apply => Run
```

Comment: I already have all 3 those dependencies in my build.gradle desktop module, ony instead of 1.9.9, I have $gdxVersion, I will update my question to show my entire desktop module in build.gradle, please check it if you can.

Comment: I tried removing everything else from my desktop module in build.gradle, and just putting what you had, but that brings me back to an old error that I got when first trying to make a desktop distributable, which is: Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/ApplicationListener
, which I had since fixed.

Comment: Your answer didn't directly help but it led me to finding a solution. While your version worked when running a standalone desktop jar created by the command `gradle desktop:dist`, I was still having problems even after making changes to make mine more like yours, by changing my gdxVersion from 1.9.9 to 1.9.8, my roboVMVersion from 2.3.5 to 2.3.3 and removing google(), which it didn't like because I have an html module too, so I looked for other differences and I found you were using gradle version 2.14.1 in the Project Structure & I was using 4.10.1, so I changed that, but then it started...

Comment: ...complaining about the other gradle settings I had to accomodate the various other platforms I had, such as html, android and ios (roboVM), so I resolved to simply create a project with just desktop using the libgdx tool, and now a java standalone works, and it wasn't because of the differences in versions, just some conflicting settings for other platforms, so I solution will be simply to have two copies of the same project side by side, one for desktop & 1 for all other platforms & just copy the same code (& even more than 2 copies if it turns out that gradle settings for any other...

Comment: ...platforms end up conflicting with each other)

Comment: Please note, a typo in my comment 2 above this one, where I said "so I solution", I meant to say "so my solution", and I tried to edit that, but I was too late, it was 9 minutes after, and the system will apparently only edit my comment up to 5 minutes after making it.

Comment: The above solution that I explained that I came too is clearly not ideal, but will have to make do, unless I or anyone else can find a better solution.